# Getting a weird null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get a null pointer exception at this line :

```
private ArrayList<DrawableEntity> entitiesToDraw = Loader.instance().getDrawableEntities();
```

There is apparently no problem with the constructor of Loader :

```
public static Loader instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        new Loader();
        System.out.println("Loader ready");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Because I get the message "Loader ready".
I don't understand, the problem seem to be before the call to getDrawableEntities() but I see nothing and it is not inside getDrawableEntities().

Comment: Nothing weird about it.

Comment: If you step through this code in a debugger, the source of your "weird" problem would be obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static Loader instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Loader();
        System.out.println("Loader ready");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

You forgot to asign your `instance` variable

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to assign it to `instance`

```
   public static Loader instance() {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Loader();
        System.out.println("Loader ready");
       }
     return instance;
   }
```

And by the way, if thats a singleton then it's wrong (not thread-safe), [Here's a way to implement the singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java).

Comment: @Spooky Then it's fine, but can you guarantee that?You shouldn't take such assumptions that might not be true in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I know, re-usability, but I don't really understand the way it is done in your link, do I have to change the loader class to an enum ?

Comment: @Spooky Exactly, you change to an enum , Watch this if you found it hard to understand  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi_I7oD_uGI#t=28m50s

Comment: I understood, I have made some change of course, everything work except that Loader need a string (gameName) to be initialized, but how to pass a parameter to the constructor if I can't access it ?
I can't put the gameName field in the enum, there is an error : 
Syntax error on token "String", strictfp expected

Comment: @Spooky Singletons cannot take parameters, I think it's not the right pattern for you.

Comment: Yes I know but without the enum I can initialize this field before the instance is created :
public static String gameName;

Comment: Adding synchronized to the constructor or the instance() method can avoid problem too, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting instance value when its null. It should be:

```
if (instance == null) {
    instance = new Loader();
    System.out.println("Loader ready");
}
```